# ContourPlot[x^( I y) == -1, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -4, 4}] plotting

Tags: plotting, complex

How to

```
ContourPlot[x^( I y) == -1, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

passing through $(x,y)= (e,π) $ without logarithmic manipulation?

The pair $(e,π)$ is not  unique out of the Euler complex number relation, a set of real pairs exists.

Comment: Is it not just a single point which satisfies the relation? Then how can you have a `ContourPlot`? I think the best you can do is to plot a `Re` and `Im` `Contourplot` of `x^( I y)`.

Comment: @Sumit `x^(I y) == -1 /. {x -> 2, y -> (2 Pi/Log[2^2])}`

Comment: Is my attempt towards visualizing a surface ( next related post today) make sense? when indulging in some ( mathematics, not mathematica) excursions?

Comment: Is my attempt towards visualizing a surface ( next related post today) make sense? when indulging in some ( mathematics, not mathematica) excursions? Is the last Plot3D you gave here before level curves at its right already an answer to the next question?

Answer (score 7):

Mindless, so maybe wrong if I missed your point, approach:

```
sol = Solve[
  Thread[ComplexExpand[ReIm[x^(I y)]] == {-1, 0}],
  y,
  Reals
]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[ Evaluate[Join @@ Table[
    ({x, y} /. sol /. C[1] -> c), {c, -10, 10}]
    ]
  , {x, 0, 5}
  , Frame -> True
  , Axes -> False
  , AspectRatio -> 1
  , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize@7, Point @ {E, Pi}}
]
```

[image]

`ContourPlot` failed to help because the expression does not cross `-1`, only 'touches' it:

```
 Plot3D[
     Evaluate[{ComplexExpand@Re[x^(I y)], -1}]
   , {x, 0.4, 4}, {y,  0.4, 4}
 ]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot3D[Evaluate[{ComplexExpand@Re[x^(I y)], -1}], {x, 0.4, 
    5}, {y, -10, 10}, ViewPoint -> Top, PlotPoints -> 50],
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    Join @@ Table[({x, y} /. sol /. C[1] -> c), {c, -2, 2}]], {x, 0, 
    5}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-10, 10}}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize@7, Point@{E, Pi}}]
  }]
```

[image]